# Rails : Multi-tenancy using Apartment and MySQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multi-tenant, apartment-gem

I'm creating an application (on rails 6.0.1) using the Apartment gem & Devise, but i can't figure out how to make it work using MySQL..

I've made all my config and stuff, generating my User devise model etc. but when i'm trying to `rails db:migrate` an error occurs :

```
Migrating  tenant
Error while connecting to tenant : Mysql2::Error: No database selected
```

Meaning i havent configured Apartment correctly to work with my Mysql database right? I couldn't find any informations (that i can understand in beginner terms) on how to connect it correctly. My `database.yml` has the following :

```
// database.yml

default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8mb4
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  username: myusername
  password: mypassword
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

(...)
```

Note that i have the good username and password in my rails app :)
Everything worked fine until i've tried to create the multitenancy stuff. Meaning the issue is maybe coming from my `config/initializers/apartment.rb` file?

Here is what it looks like right now

```
// config/initializers/apartment.rb
require 'apartment/elevators/subdomain'
Apartment.configure do |config|
  config.excluded_models = %w[User]
  config.tenant_names = -> { User.pluck :subdomain }
  config.use_schemas = true
end

Rails.application.config.middleware.use Apartment::Elevators::Subdomain
```

**Edit** : I'm using the development branch from Apartment. Maybe it's an issue with Rails 6?

```
// Gemfile

gem 'apartment', github: 'influitive/apartment', branch: 'development'
```

Comment: Are you still having this issue? Set the use_schemas to false since you're using mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess by now you solved your problem but for those who came here searching to deal with multi tenancy in Rails 6. A couple of things I found by myself:

- Apartment doesn't support Rails 6.
- Even Apartment's developer [doesn't recommend to use his multi schema approach](https://influitive.io/our-multi-tenancy-journey-with-postgres-schemas-and-apartment-6ecda151a21f). They recommend [citusdata's activerecord-multi-tenant gem](https://github.com/citusdata/activerecord-multi-tenant)
- I find [this post](https://realptsdengineer.com/ruby-on-rails-multitenancy-in-2020/) very helpful for my doubts.